# New WebForms Application Template FriendlyUrl and Css not working on Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I created a new project from Visual Studio 2013, it is a basic web application using 4.5

I added some style and content to the default page. When I run it locally using the debug it looks good. However, I publish it like my other sites on my server the friendly url pages are 404 and no style is applied from the bundle. There are not any errors to easily see what is going on. Does anyone have a quick fix so I don't have to dive in deep wasting lots of time?

Running Win Server 2008 R2 and IIS 6.1

**Please see my code at:**  https://github.com/ad5qa/SARGroups

Image A - Visual Studio IIS Express
[image]

Image B - From Server
[image]

Comment: Are you bundling the CSS? What is the relative path to your CSS (i.e. `/Content/css/bootstrap.css`)?

Comment: I am using the default bundling:
    <bundles version="1.0">
      <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
        <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
      </styleBundle>
    </bundles>

Comment: Using VS Debug and looking at the source I find the .css in the page. ON the server it does not exist. Nor does the FriendlyUrls work. Has to be a config issue. I am using the same scheme of bundling in another web app but not friendly urls.

Answer (score 0):

When you are bundling, the bundle is served using `/Content/css`. Since this file does not have an extension, you need to configure IIS 6 to handle this request. This is probably also the case with your FriendlyUrls

You should be able to use the following solution from Phil Haack to solve both problems:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx/

Comment: Nope same thing, not getting anywhere.